# Pass variable in where subquery in collection

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

I have a query that also includes a subquery as shown below

```
SELECT product.entity_id product_entity_id
FROM catalog_product_flat_1 as product
WHERE product.entity_id NOT IN 
 (SELECT product_id 
  FROM sales_order_item AS oi2 
  WHERE oi2.created_at BETWEEN "2012-09-03 00:00:00" AND "2012-09-05 00:00:00")
```

But I want to pass a variable into this query like from and to date. But I don't know how to do it in the _initselect() function.

```
 $this->getSelect()
    ->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
    ->columns([
        'entity_id', 
        'name', 
        'sku'
    ])
    ->where('entity_id NOT IN (select product_id from sales_order_item where sales_order_item.created_at > $fromDate and sales_order_item.created_at < $toDate)');
```

Not sure how to pass the to and from date

Answer (score 0):

I think something likes this

```
->where('entity_id NOT IN (select product_id from sales_order_item where sales_order_item.created_at > "'.$fromDate.'" and sales_order_item.created_at < "'.$toDate.'")');
```

Comment: Where did the $fromDate came from? How it's being submitted?